# Overloading push_back() in vector to allow non-duplicate elements

Tags: c++, vector, set, push-back, unordered-set

Can we overload the `push_back()` method in `std::vector` to allow non-duplicate elements? I know `std::set` and `std::unordered_set` are supposed to avoid duplicate elements, but `std::set` sorts the elements and `std::unordered_set` stores the elements in no particular order. I need to retrieve the elements in the order they are inserted, while ensuring duplicate elements are not inserted.

Edit: There's a possible duplicate for this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716997/queue-with-unique-entries-in-c). The best solution to this duplicate proposes to have an auxiliary data structure and another custom method "add". This doesn't look good for me since(I'll put it in a separate documentation) the users inserting data in `std::vector` rarely refer to the documentation for any custom functions. If there's no efficient way though, this can be a last resort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Queue with unique entries in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716997/queue-with-unique-entries-in-c)

Comment: If you really want to do that: Better to wrap a push_back-activity in a new function. Then use std::find, and check, if the element is in the vector and if not, then push_back. Otherwise not. That has the same effect then overwriting such a function which is not recommended at all

Answer (score 3):

Many people advise against it, but it seems there's some kind of urban legend going around that doing so will cause the universe to undergo vacuum decay and reality as we know it will dissolve.

You can publicly inherit from `std::vector`. But you have to think about what you can do with that.

If you inherit from `vector`, it is highly recommended that you don't add any data members to it. This can cause object slicing (google "c++ object slicing".) You also need to keep in mind that `vector` is not using virtual functions. That means you cannot override member functions. You can only shadow them, so it's not guaranteed that it will always be your `push_back()` function that gets called. The original will get called if you pass an object of your class to something that takes a reference to a `vector`, for example.

So in the end, you'd need to add a `push_back_unique()` function instead. But that in turns means that can be served by a simple free function instead. So inheriting `vector` isn't needed. This of course means there's never a guarantee that the elements in the vector will be unique. Other code might use `push_back()` instead somewhere.

Inheriting `vector` makes sense if you want to add completely new convenience functions that don't impose or lift any restrictions that `vector` has. If you want something that looks like a `vector` but really isn't (because it has different behavior and/or restrictions), you should implement your own type that delegates the container functionality to `vector` by either inheriting privately from it, or by having it as a private data member, and then replicate the `vector` API through public wrapper functions.

But this is very tedious to implement. Usually, you don't really need all the API from vector. So I'd say just write a smaller class around vector that only provides the functionality you need. And that functionality sounds like it's going to be pretty much read-only, since allowing write access to the elements allows for setting an element to the same value as another, breaking the container's uniqueness. So you could do something like:

```
template<typename T>
class UniqueVector
{
public:
    void push_back(T&& elem)
    {
        if (std::find(vec_.begin(), vec_.end(), elem) == vec_.end()) {
            vec_.push_back(std::forward(elem));
        }
    }

    const T& operator[](size_t index) const
    {
        return vec_[index];
    }

    auto begin() const
    {
        return vec_.cbegin();
    }

    auto end() const
    {
        return vec_.cend();
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> vec_;
};
```

If you still want to allow write access to individual elements, then you can provide non-const functions that check if the value that is passed is already in the vector. Like:

```
void assign_if_unique(size_t index, T&& value)
{
    if (std::find(vec_.begin(), vec_.end(), value) == vec_.end()) {
        vec_[index] = std::forward(value);
    }
}
```

This is a minimal example. You should obviously add the functions you actually want. Like `size()`, `empty()`, and whatever else you need.

Comment: Whilst tedious, it's fairly simple to fill in a number of members. You can basically copy from [`[queue]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/queue)

Answer (score 1):

You should first define a free function<sup>1</sup> to implement your feature:

```
template<class T>
std::vector<T>&
push_back_unique(std::vector<T>& dest, T const& src)
{ /* ... */ }
```

If you use this a lot, and if make sense regarding your program, you *might* want to define an operator to do so:

```
template<class T>
std::vector<T>& operator<<(std::vector<T>& dest, T const& src)
{ return push_back_unique(dest, src); }
```

This allows:

```
std::vector<int> data;
data << 5 << 8 << 13 << 5 << 21;
for (auto n : data) std::cout << n << " "; // prints 5 8 13 21
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> This is because inheriting from standard containers is often bad practice and brings pitfalls.